# ¿Cómo obtengo una consulta SQL mediante el siguiente modelo de base de datos?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Tengo el siguiente modelo de bases de datos em PostgreSQL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba tratando de hacer una consulta que me mostrara el nombre del jugador y el puntaje asociado a través de la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT j.nombre, d.puntaje 
FROM   jugador j, puntaje d, juegojugador 
WHERE  juegojugador.idjuegojugador=puntaje.idjuegojugador AND
       juegojugador.idjugaor=jugador.idjugaor;
```

Sin embargo, la consola no me muestra nada. Hace ya un tiempo que aprendí de esto y no recuerdo muy bien, sé que toca hacer la intersección entre las llaves foraneas y primarias, pero no logro distinguir el error.

Apreciaría mucho la ayuda y uno que otro lugar para reforzar los conocimientos de SQL.

Comment: Hola Daniel, verifica que las tablas tienen datos. SELECT * FROM jugador ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu consulta SQL formateada:

```
SELECT j.nombre, d.puntaje
  FROM jugador j, puntaje d, juegojugador
 WHERE juegojugador.idjuegojugador = puntaje.idjuegojugador
   AND juegojugador.idjugaor = jugador.idjugaor;
```

El problema no es con las mayúsculas o las minúsculas de los identificadores. Para PostgreSQL le da igual eso.

El problema es que una vez que le asignas un alias a una tabla, ya no puedes usar el nombre de la tabla en las condiciones del SQL, si no que tienes que seguir usando el alias de forma coherente.

Por ejemplo. en tu caso, tu consulta debería haberte dado el error siguiente (ver [demostración](http://rextester.com/BGY91673)):

> 42P01: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "puntaje"

Esto se debe a que haces referencia a `puntaje.idjuegojugador`, cuando deberías estar usando el alias `d`: `d.idjuegojugador`. El mismo error sucede con la expresión `jugador.idjugaor` que debería usar el alias `j`: `j.idjugaor`.

Con estas 2 correcciones (sin tener que cambiar las mayúsculas o minúsculas), la consulta funciona bien (ver [demostración](http://rextester.com/SHNER51405)):

```
SELECT j.nombre, d.puntaje
  FROM jugador j, puntaje d, juegojugador
 WHERE juegojugador.idjuegojugador = d.idjuegojugador
   AND juegojugador.idjugaor = j.idjugaor;
```

Nota que `juegojugador.idjuegojugador` y `juegojugador.idjugaor` no causan error porque no le asignastes un alias a la tabla `juegojugador` (aunque probablemente sería mejor que lo hicieras para mantener coherencia en tu consulta).

**Nota adicional**

Adicionalmente, te sugiero de ir acostumbrándote a expresar tus joins de la forma estándar siguiente (ver [demostración](http://rextester.com/VKN35257)):

```
select j.nombre, p.puntaje
  from jugador j
  join juegojugador jj
    on jj.idjugaor = j.idjugaor
  join puntaje p
    on p.idjuegojugador = jj.idjuegojugador;
```

Esta forma de expresar los joins es más legible, es el estándar aceptado, y simplifica modificar la consulta cuando necesites expresar "outer joins" y así por el estilo.

Comment: No uso Postgre pero tu respuesta me pareció muy profesional +1. Soluciones típicas de "pan para hoy, hambre mañana" (es decir, con cero justificación técnica) no me gustan. No es tu caso. Excelente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelente explicación!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
SELECT j.nombre, d.puntaje FROM Jugador j, Puntaje d, JuegoJugador WHERE JuegoJugador.idJuegoJugador=d.idJuegoJugador AND JuegoJugador.idJugaor=j.idJugaor;
```

Por si fuera el típico error de mayusculas y minusculas.

Comment: Gracias! en definitiva era eso

Comment: Un placer ayudar

Comment: Me parece raro que esto haya arreglado el problema. Para PostgreSQL, mayuscula o minuscula, da igual.